# PHP - Is it possible to continue foreach inside other page?

Tags: php

IIs it possible to do something like that:

```
foreach ($var as $val){

//code here

//code to continue

}
```

and call the foreach again inside other function:

```
foreach ($var as $val){

//code to continue

//loop continuation

}
```

Comment: May I ask WHY you want to do this? AFAIK it is possible, but tell us what you are trying to achieve and I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do it

Comment: Try it out and let us know.

Comment: I'm using the MVC structure in PHP, and i have one loop inside model to update multiple rows, but this loop only works if i insert all the POSTS inside this loop, but i can't do it because i'm following the MVC rules, and i have to insert every POST inside the controller, the problem is if i insert all the POSTS inside the controller, i just can update the last row, because the POSTS aren't inside the loop. Resuming, i can't put the POSTS inside the loop in model, so i want to begin this loop in model, and continue in controller.

Comment: I'm confused as to why your model can't see the data your controller can.  Maybe if you show us some of your code, we could help find a more elegant solution?

Comment: I tried to expain in this question, but my english is horrible, sorry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155372/mvc-php-foreach-inside-the-model-and-posts-inside-the-view

Answer (score 0):

You can call `foreach` as many times as you want. You just need to pass this array/object to other function somehow. Every time you call `foreach` it will iterate from beginning.